# How to change color of border line in TextFormField with Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I would like to change the color of the border line in TextFormField.
I would like to change the color blue to white.

[image]

I can not guess any of their properties.

```
              child: TextFormField(
                onChanged: (value) {
                  email = value;
                },
                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
                autofocus: true,
                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                cursorColor: Colors.white,
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                  filled: true,
                  fillColor: kTileColor,
                  enabledBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
                    borderSide: BorderSide(
                        style: BorderStyle.none, color: Colors.white),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
```

How can I do it?

Comment: Accept my answer if you found it useful so others can see the importance @tajiihiro

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only set the `enabledBorder` property to `white`. Set the `focusedBorder` property to `white` and it will give you your desired result.

You can achieve this by setting the `focusedBorder` property to your desired color.

Check the code below, it works fine:

```
            child: TextFormField(
                onChanged: (value) {
                  email = value;
                },
                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
                autofocus: true,
                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                cursorColor: Colors.white,
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                  filled: true,
                  fillColor: kTileColor,
                  enabledBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
                    borderSide: BorderSide(
                        style: BorderStyle.none, color: Colors.white),
                  ),
                ),
                 // set the focused border property here
                  focusedBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
                    borderSide: BorderSide(
                        style: BorderStyle.none, color: Colors.white),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
```